# Modify this function to show/hide by data-attributes instead of by class

Tags: jquery, show-hide, custom-data-attribute

I'd like to use this show/hide function by data-attributes instead of class, but I'm having a hard time getting the syntax right.

I know that it's something like this `$("li[data-color=" + this.value + "]").show();` but I haven't been able to get it to work and/or modify the function so that it works.

I'm using the function to filter clothing by various attributes (i.e. color, product-category, occasion, etc.), and I've posted a fiddle with a simple example here: http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/WZpMh/4/

```
$('#filterOptions li a').click(function () {
    var ourClass = $(this).attr('class');
    $('#filterOptions li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    if (ourClass == 'all') {
        $('#content').find('.item').show();
    } else {
        $('#content').find('.item:not(.' + ourClass + ')').hide();
        $('#content').find('.item.' + ourClass).show();
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/awNdC/ (line 16)

Comment: @valtron - It's good to know that I got the syntax right ;-) How would I use that to be able to filter by the data-attributes instead of by class?

Comment: @raphaelvalerio - I couldn't upvote your post because you'd deleted it, but I wanted to give you a shout-out for showing me what was wrong with my syntax (I was missing the quotes around the value in the data-color attribute) :-D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please see this fiddle for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Cr2cY/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#filterOptions li a').click(function () {
        // fetch the class of the clicked item
        var ourDataAttr = $(this).data('color');
        // reset the active class on all the buttons
        $('#filterOptions li').removeClass('active');
        // update the active state on our clicked button
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        if (ourDataAttr == 'All') {
            // show all our items
            $('#content').find('.item').show();
        } else {
            // hide all elements that don't share ourClass
            $('#content').find('.item:not([data-color="' + ourDataAttr + '"])').hide();
            // show all elements that do share ourClass
            $('#content').find('.item[data-color="' + ourDataAttr + '"]').show();
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Note that you were comparing 'all' with 'All' in your fiddle, which will not match.

Comment: OMG! That's perfect :-D And my bad on typo in the fiddle (I blame it on the headache I've gotten trying to figure this out ;-))